Tutorial from the OPA-Website for Istio is not working as it should
I followed all these steps here:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/
And then all steps for the Opa-Istio-Tutorial here:
https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/envoy-tutorial-istio/
I don't get any erros, but when I try to test it, like it is described here:
curl --user alice:password -i http://$SERVICE_HOST/productpage
curl --user alice:password -i http://$SERVICE_HOST/api/v1/products

The outcome is always:
curl --user alice:password -i http://$SERVICE_HOST/productpage

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-length: 19
content-type: text/plain
date: Sun, 07 Apr 2024 11:31:44 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 14

and
curl --user alice:password -i http://$SERVICE_HOST/api/v1/products

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-length: 19
content-type: text/plain
date: Sun, 07 Apr 2024 11:31:50 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1

Problem: The first should be allowed as in the rego defined in this example, but it is not working, it shows BOTH times forbidden. And yes, I donfigured the mesh before and added the external Provider like described in the example:
data:
  mesh: |-
    # Add the following lines to define the ServiceEntry previously created as an external authorizer:
    extensionProviders:
    - name: opa-ext-authz-grpc
      envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
        service: opa-ext-authz-grpc.local
        port: "9191"    `


I am using minikube with Docker on macOS m2.
It would be great if someone could give me a hint.
Installed serveral times istio and opa. Tried to find comprable issues in the web. Tried to find an answer with the opa documentation.

Do you see any requests in the logs of the OPA container?

Thanks Charlie for the hint! The logs were fine, but I found that this command :
kubectl edit configmap -n istio-system istio

does not work properly from the terminal: I can add these lines:
    extensionProviders:
- name: opa-ext-authz-grpc
  envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
    service: opa-ext-authz-grpc.local
    port: "9191"

but they seem to be out of order. I then tried the same with Visual Studio code by overwriting the mesh and it finally worked.
